# Vuejs 2 v-on:click.prevent()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to know what these options people are using more.

1) Using v-on on normal (div, span, etc) element

```
<div v-on:click="myFunction" class="cursor-pointer">Click me<div>
```

Here, it requires to have the a class to set up the pointer cursor to indicate that is can be clicked, and also, to increase the UX.

1) Using v-on on link element
Click me
Here, doesn't need to have any classe to set up the pointer cursor. However, it requires the prevent mode to stop the link action.

So, What is the best practice, advantages and drawbacks of these two approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, it doesn't really matter. Generally speaking though, you should be writing your HTML dom in Vue.js the same way you would write it without Vue.js. If something should be a link because it's leading to another view in your application, then `<a>` makes sense. If you wouldn't normally use an anchor link if it was just a static HTML page, then you're probably better to be writing it with a `div`, `span`, or whatever your developer instincts decide in that case.

Always try to write your code as if someone else is going to be looking at it, in which case they are going to have some expectation of what an `<a>` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Tks! It makes sense once link should lead user to another page. Action to open and close panels for example could be just a div or span or whatever.

Comment: If it's not a link, use a `<button>` element rather than a `<div>` or `<span>`. Otherwise screenreader users  won't know that that a clickable element is even there. This is what a `<button>` is for.